# Is there a way to speed up the triggering of a Power Automate workflow (Cloud)?

Tags: power-automate

I have a few Power Automate workflows that are triggered when:

1. An XLSX file is created/modified
2. A JSON file has been created/modified
3. An HTML file has been created/modified

on designated SharePoint folders. Each case takes up to 5 minutes to trigger and therefore, the whole process takes more than 15 minutes in total. Is there a way to speed up the triggering of the workflows?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean a user changes a file and it takes 5 minutes after the file change for the trigger to occur?

Comment: Hi @Skin. Yes, that is exactly what is happening. I have searched for solutions but so far I could not get any substantial answer.

Comment: Have you thought about raising it with Microsoft?

Comment: Not really because I have read the postings of others who have actually raised this case. I was just wondering if someone has any workaround or a solution for it. Thank you for your comment though.

Comment: Nup, they used to have additional settings on connectors like these so that you could control how often they would poll for new/updated content, they no longer exist though and they don't even exist in LogicApps either.  I'd raise it with Microsoft through a support channel, not via an online forum.  They'll give you a straight answer for sure.

Comment: I see, good point! I will do it today and update this post when I get their reply.